# How to pause receiving stream of data (TCP protocol) in C#?

Tags: c#, tcp

did anyone can tell me how to pause the receiving stream of data in my code please ?
For the moment, my script (see below) is able to :
- wait for data
- read data (TCP protocol) as soon as data are streaming from a third party software

--> I'm stuck with how it would be possible to implement code to pause the streaming of data as soon as I receive one character ('a' or 'b' in my exemple). I heard about the use of a buffer by I'm very new with implementation of such kind of protocole.

My final goal is to have a loop in which a third party software send "a" or "b" to UNITY, using TCP protocol, then UNITY receive "a" or "b", and update the color of an object based on this character.

Thanks for your help,

Yannick

```
// Initialization of the script 
void Start() 
{ 
    _renderer = GetComponent(); 
    listener = new TcpListener(55001); 
    listener.Start(); 
    print("is listening"); 
}

void Update()
{
    if (!listener.Pending())
    { }
    else
    {
        print("socket comes");
        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ns);
        coherence = reader.ReadToEnd();
        print(coherence);
    }

    if (coherence == "a")
    {
        colorFin = Color.green;
    }
    else if (coherence == "b")
    {
        colorFin = Color.yellow;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you format your code you might get people to spend more time on your question

Comment: I took the liberty to format it for you

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but I think something like this should work:

```
...
else
{
    print("socket comes");
    TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ns);
    while (true)
    {
        char coherence = (char)reader.Read());
        print(coherence);

        //... handle colors and whatever you want...
    }

}
```

since StreamReader.Read reads one character at a time.

You probably want some logic to perform the work in a Task or Thread, and handle incorrect received data. But that is out of the scope for this question, I think.